# Populating a spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I am busy with an android application where i get data from my database that a user can choose in the spinner. Here is the code for that:

```
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerfabric);
    connect = CONN(un, passwords, db, ip);

    String query = "select * from fabric";
    try {
        connect = CONN(un, passwords, db, ip);
        stmt = connect.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String id = rs.getString("FabricName");
            data.add(id);
        }
        String[] array = data.toArray(new String[0]);
        ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
        spinnerfabric.setAdapter(NoCoreAdapter);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    spinnerfabric.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
            String name = spinnerfabric.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Toast.makeText(ForSpinner.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Now i got this working where i show the fabric names but what i want to do is when the user clicks on fabric i want to display the fabric price on the `toast`.
for example when the user clicks on the spinner for fabricA the toast must show the price of FabricA which is also in my database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get `name` by from the list of data using this line :

```
String name = data.get(position);
Toast.makeText(context,name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: I got the name but i also want to get the price so for example when the user clicks on the spinner for fabricA the toast must show the price of FabricA which is also in my database

Comment: As you are having an array for name, like wise make one more array of price,  and get ther corresponding price using the position.

Comment: I created another array but how do i set it to an edit text, please see updated question [New question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52578215/populate-edit-text-from-spinner)